# When does dereferencing a pointer cause a copy to be made in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, dereference

Basically I am curious when dereferencing a pointer causes a copy to be made. It is my understanding that pointers are a high level construct, and that if you dereference into a reference variable, it does not make a copy, but if you dereference into a variable, it does make a copy.

So this would not make a copy:

```
int num = 10;
int *ptr = &num;
int& num2 = *ptr;
```

But this would:

```
int num = 10;
int *ptr = &num;
int num2 = *ptr;
```

Is that correct? When exactly does referencing cause a copy to be made if ever?

Comment: Referencing just gives a different name to an object, and hence does not cause a copy.

Comment: Deferencing pointer doesn't cause copy, `int n = someValue;` does copy.

Comment: Seems like maybe I'm conflating the ideas of references and pointers a little bit, but thank you. This was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dereferencing alone never makes a copy. Though dereferencing a pointer is just applying the `*` operator and there is more happening in your code.

Here:

```
int num = 10;
int *ptr = &num;
int& num2 = *ptr;
```

the last line dereferences the pointer and uses the result to initialize the reference `num2`. `num2` now references `num`. No copies.

Here:

```
int num = 10;
int *ptr = &num;
int num2 = *ptr;
```

in the last line you first derference `ptr` then use the result to initialize `num2`. As `num2` is a value a copy is made.

You do not need pointers to see the same effect:

```
int x = 42;
int& y = x;   // no copy, y is an alias for x
int z = x;    // z is a copy of x
```

Comment: I see. I think I was conflating reference variables and dereferencing pointers since they share similar names. This was clear and makes sense though; thank you.